# How conditionally negate an AVX2 int16_t vector based on another vector of 0 or 1 elements?

Tags: c++, optimization, simd, avx, avx2

I have a vector `int16_t beta = {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0}`.

I want to implement this equation with AVX2

[image]

```
c[i] = a[i] + (-1)^beta[i] * b[i]
```

where a, b, c, and beta are all AVX2 vectors of `int16_t`.

---

I have figured out that, if I can map 1 to -32768 multiplication operation can be avoided. I mean, flipping the sign of vector b can be done using OR and NEGATE functions of simd intrinsics.

I do know that 1 can be mapped to -32768 using left shift operation, however avx2 doesn't have any bit shift operations<sup>1</sup>. Is there any way to efficiently map 1 to -32768 with simd?

---

Editor's footnote 1:  [`_mm256_slli_epi16(x, 15)`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=4067,602,2978&text=shift&techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2) does in fact exist.  But there are other ways to implement the whole formula so the question is interesting after all.

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understand your question, but maybe the answer is `_mm256_slli_epi16(x, 15)` ?

Comment: How many bits do you want `beta` to have? 8 or 16?

Comment: `beta` has 16 bits

Comment: More `_mm256_blendv_epi8` could be of interest to blend between `b[i]` and `-b[i]`.

Comment: @wim That appears to unfortunately operate on byte-sized chunks, not individual bits.

Comment: _mm256_slli_epi16 instruction solved my problem. In addition to that it has very low latency for integers. thanks @wim

Comment: If you didn't find shift intrinsics, you're probably looking in the wrong place.  [A search for `shift` on Intel's intrinsics finder](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=4067,602,2978&text=shift&techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2) (with AVX512 filtered out to avoid clutter) finds them all.  Or look at an asm reference guide http://felixcloutier.com/x86/index.html (which lists intrinsics.)  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sse/info for more links to guides/resources.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Yes, that is right, but with an extra `_mm256_cmpeq_epi16` you can expand the byte width to 16 bits.

Comment: To negate a vector, subtract it from 0.  `__m256i neg = _mm256_sub_epi16(_mm256_setzero_si256(),  input_vector);`  x86 doesn't have a SIMD negate instruction.  @wim: you might blend `a[i]-b[i]` with `a[i]+b[i]`.  Or not, I think Harold's answer is better.

Comment: If `beta` only has 1 useful bit per element, consider storing it more compactly to save memory bandwidth / cache footprint.  Use [is there an inverse instruction to the movemask instruction in intel avx2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36491672) to turn a packed bitmap back into a SIMD vector.  The extra instructions that takes are fast enough that you'll still bottleneck on memory bandwidth unless your data is hot in L1d or maybe L2, for this 3-input / 1-output operation, if you aren't doing anything else with `c` while it's already loaded.

Comment: @PeterCordes I did think of storing as packed bits, However I need to access bit by bit for extracting/interleaving so i decided to store as integers, may be I should try to find a way to efficiently perform those operations with packed bits. thanks for the suggestion and awesome editing of question

Comment: On Intel CPUs, [`pext`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=4067,602,2978,4071&techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,Other&text=pext_) is efficient, so you can turn a vector of 16-bit compare results into a bitmap using `unsigned bitmap8 = _mm256_movemask_epi8` / `bitmap16 = _pext_u32(bitmap8, 0baaaaaaaa)`.  Without BMI2 `pext`, you might just leave your bitmap interleaved with zeros, so you have 32 bits per 16 elements, with the low bit of every pair being garbage (or mask it to `0`, or make it always match the significant bit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a quick way to conditionally negate, using `_mm256_sign_epi16`. The mask is not of the right form, but it can be transformed into the right form by adding 0x7FFF to every element, so:

```
__m256i masks = _mm256_add_epi16(beta, _mm256_set1_epi16(0x7FFF));
__m256i res = _mm256_add_epi16(a, _mm256_sign_epi16(b, masks));
```

Comment: But `masks` is negative or zero here, isn't it? While we need `masks` to be positive or negative? Nevertheless, `_mm256_sign_epi16` is a great idea in this context.

Comment: @wim: masks is 0 or 1.  So we get either `0x7FFF` (positive) or `0x8000` (negative).  If `masks` came from a `cmpeq` or something and was 0 or all-ones (`-1` = `0xffff`), you'd want to add `0x8000` to get `0x7fff` or `0x8000`.  Or subtract `masks` *from* that to get the opposite mapping.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, right, I overlooked that. Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can transform

```
c[i] = a[i] + (-1)^beta[i] * b[i]
```

to

```
c[i] = a[i] - (beta[i] AND b[i]) + ((NOT beta[i]) AND b[i])
```

as the original formula translates to "subtract this bit if beta[i] is set, otherwise add it".
*(I have no idea what you intend to happen for `c[i] = 0 + (-1) * 1` or `c[i] = 1 + 1 * 1` - I'm assuming normal arithmetic addition with carries here, contrary to the index notation).*
So you can just drop the indices:

```
c = a - (beta & b) + (!beta & b)
```

I don't know if that has a good mapping to AVX2 intrinsics but I would suspect it does.