# Bit scatter over multiple NEON registers

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

What is the most efficient way to spread bits from memory evenly over multiple vector registers? All data must end up in the least-significant bits of the target registers.

For example, how can 2 bytes from memory be spread over 8 words (in two lanes)?

```
      V0.S4             |  V1.S4
S[3]: [data bit 6 + 7]  |  [data bit 14 + 15]
S[2]: [data bit 4 + 5]  |  [data bit 12 + 13]
S[1]: [data bit 2 + 3]  |  [data bit 10 + 11]
S[0]: [data bit 0 + 1]  |  [data bit 8 + 9]
```

The 8, 16 and 32-bit split-up is easy with `LD1` and widening instructions. A 3-bit split-up may be messy.

Comment: Probably broadcast, shift with a per-element variable count, and mask.  Similar to some strategies for bitmap to vector mask on x86 ([is there an inverse instruction to the movemask instruction in intel avx2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36488675) links various ideas).  With more than 1 bit per element, you wouldn't be using a mask+compare, but ARM has much better variable-count shifts than x86.  (Although x86 can shift variable amounts within 32-bit elements with AVX2 `vpsrlvd`, but not narrower.)

Comment: That is exactly what I feared Peter. Too many operations mitigate the wins made with parallel processing. UBFX is King.

Comment: Load + broadcast + shift + AND is only 4 operations and gives you 4 results that can be stored with a single store.  If you ultimately want the results in scalar GP registers, then for sure just UBFX, or `and` with a shifted source operand, otherwise SIMD seems like a clear win, especially if you have some SIMD processing to do with the result.

Comment: `ld1r` is load+broadcast in one instruction.  I might try a 32-bit `ld1r`, four 4S shifts by appropriate preloaded vectors, and four ANDs.  This processes 4 bytes of input, making 16 words of output, and short dependency chains.

Comment: Oh wait, `ld4r` is four load+broadcast.  Expensive, but then you can heat up all the pipelines by processing 16 bytes of input into 16 registers.

Comment: Problem is that you can't shift vector parts individually @NateEldredge. So the best we've got for the example is 2 `LDRB`, 8 `UBFX` and 8 `VMOV`.

Comment: @PascaldeKloe: Yes you can; that's what [`USHL` (register)](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0801/l/A64-SIMD-Vector-Instructions/USHL--vector---A64-?lang=en) does (and its friend `SSHL`).  Despite the name it also does right shifts if you specify a negative shift count.  So your two-byte scatter can be done with one `LD1R`, two `USHL` and two vector `AND`.  Plus a couple extra instructions to initialize registers with the shift counts and mask - but assuming this will be done in a loop, the initialization only needs to be done once.

Comment: Oh good, ARM has broadcast-load as a single instruction (like x86 with AVX), so only 3 operations per vector of results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vector `USHL`/`SSHL` allow for per-element shift counts, where negative counts produce a right shift.  So follow it with a mask and you are in business.

Start by initializing some registers with our needed constants.  This only needs to be done once.

```
V8.4S = { 0, -2, -4, -6 }
V9.4S = { -8, -10, -12, -14 }
V10.4S = {3, 3, 3, 3}
```

and then

```
LD1R   V2.8H, [X0]       // load 2 bytes, replicate across all elements
                       // note we only really care about half of them
USHL   V0.4S, V2.4S, V8.4S
USHL   V1.4S, V2.4S, V9.4S
AND    V0.16B, V0.16B, V10.16B
AND    V1.16B, V1.16B, V10.16B
```

Alternatively, to save a constant, you could also do

```
V8.4S = {0, -2, -4, -6}
V10.4S = {3, 3, 3, 3}

LD2R   { V2.16B, V3.16B }, [X0]
USHL   V0.4S, V2.4S, V8.4S
USHL   V1.4S, V3.4S, V8.4S
AND    V0.16B, V0.16B, V10.16B
AND    V1.16B, V1.16B, V10.16B
```

where each of the two bytes is replicated across its own register.

You can load four bytes at a time by starting with `LD1R V2.4S, [X0]` (and then four different shift count vectors) or `LD4R { V2.16B, ..., V5.16B }, [X0]` following the second approach.  You can even load 16 bytes at a time with `LD4R { V2.4S, ..., V5.4S }, [X0]` and then repeat the first version four times.

Comment: Very elegant Nate. 

Comment:  speed confirmed—got over 2× *overall* improvement with `LD4R`.

Comment: You could keep the elements 16bit until the very end where you use `uxtl/uxtl2` to make them 32bit ones. Only one shift register is required as well.