# What is the fastest way to map uint64_t {0,1} to float 64 {1.0,-1.0}?

Tags: c++, optimization, bit-manipulation

I have a 64-bit unsigned integer uint64_t flag variable called `uintflag` that can only hold the values `0` or `1`.

I need to convert `0` to `1.0` and `1` to `-1.0`. This conversion is from an uint64_t (64-bit) to a double (64-bit).

While the benchmarking is judged on an x86-64 platform, I'm writing GNU, and I don't know in what processor it may be run, so a goal is to write portable code that can run on various architectures. Therefore, to ensure correctness on different platforms, I cannot rely on x86-specific bit formats.
I prioritize correctness over performance optimization for non-x86 platforms.

In x86, the conversion of uint to double consumes 5 cycles, so this is expensive

```c++
return double(1.0 - 2.0 * uintflag);
```

An `if` is not much better, maybe because is not branchless, and branchless code tends to be faster.

```c++
return uintflag ? double(-1.0) : double(1.0);
```

I also tried an array containing float values, and using the uint as index.

This tends to be better, because is branchless, and does not do any type cast from int to double, but I suspect that it is fetched from L1 cache, which takes around 10 cycles.

```c++
double arrayMap[2] = {1.0, -1.0};    
return arrayMap[uintflag];
```

Is there any approach that ensures the array resides within CPU registers, and is not fetched from the L1 cache?

I'm getting inconsistent benchmark results. Can you help me identify the correct benchmarking approach and determine the most efficient method for converting `uintflag` to a double value?

```
Average time for getFromArray: 5768500 nanoseconds
Average time for ifBranching: 6114700 nanoseconds
Average time for mathFormulaCasingtoFloat: 6803000 nanoseconds
   
Average time for getFromArray: 8157100 nanoseconds
Average time for ifBranching: 9361300 nanoseconds
Average time for mathFormulaCasingtoFloat: 16988800 nanoseconds

Average time for getFromArray: 8792100 nanoseconds
Average time for ifBranching: 7761900 nanoseconds
Average time for mathFormulaCasingtoFloat: 8643100 nanoseconds
```

Here is the code

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef double (*conversion_function)(uint64_t);

double ifBranching(uint64_t uintflag)
{
  return uintflag ? double(-1.0) : double(1.0);
}

double arrayMap[2] = {1.0, -1.0};

double getFromArray(uint64_t uintflag)
{
  return arrayMap[uintflag];
}

double mathFormulaCasingtoFloat(uint64_t uintflag)
{
  return double(1.0 - 2.0 * uintflag);
}

int main()
{
  uint64_t uintflag = 1;

  map<string, conversion_function> conversion_functions;
  conversion_functions["ifBranching"] = ifBranching;
  conversion_functions["getFromArray"] = getFromArray;
  conversion_functions["mathFormulaCasingtoFloat"] = mathFormulaCasingtoFloat;

  const int numRuns = 100000;

  for (auto &[functionName, function] : conversion_functions)

  {
    auto totalDuration = chrono::duration<double, nano>::zero();

    for (int i = 0; i < numRuns; i++)

    {
      auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      function(uintflag);
      auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
      auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count();

      totalDuration += chrono::duration<double, nano>(duration);
    }

    auto x = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(totalDuration);
    string strDuration = to_string(x.count());
    cout << "Average time for " << functionName << ": " << strDuration << " nanoseconds" << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is virtually impossible to measure such a tiny code fragment directly. The only way that makes any sense would be to examine the assembler code generated. Even when you code an if statement the compiler can still turn it into a conditional move. In real code the conversion delay here will be masked by other neighbouring code execution. The only way to know for sure is use each one **in the environment** where it has to work quickly and check the true real world performance. BTW Unless you appear to do something with the result some global optimisers will eliminate your test code entirely.

Comment: 1.  Make `arrayMap` `constexpr`.  2.  Delay conversion to `double` in `mathFormulaCasingtoFloat`:  `return 1.0 - 2 * uintflag;`.  3.  `ifBranching` doesn't necessarily branch depending on compiler and optimization level.  Inspect the assembly to find out.

Comment: don't calculate time for each iteration, move calls to `now` outside of loop to measure total loop time

I'd add `uintflag` changing inside of loop, otherwise branch prediction will screw results

Comment: @Howard Hinnant The problem with delaying the cast, is that it does 2 casts: from unsigned to signed integer, and then to float.  
'constexpr' seems to help, (although i get inconsistent times).

Comment: Array can cause cache misses when the cache is cold. This is good in benchmark when the cache is hot. This is one of the many reasons doing realistic benchmark is hard. If you do this conversion in a big loop, then the array solution is certainly better but it depends of the other instruction in the loop (since modern x86-64 CPUs are superscalar ones with non-uniform ports). Besides, `return double(1 - 2 * int(uintflag));` should be slightly faster than `return 1.0 - 2 * uintflag;` because of the latency of a double-precision operation.

Comment: @tutizeri There is no cast to int.  2*uintflag is an unsigned expression resulting in unsigned. Then that unsigned is converted to double and the subtraction is done. But JérômeRichard has a better formulation regardless:  do the whole thing in integer and then convert the result to double.

Comment: By the way, this operation should be very fast on modern CPUs and it is hard to reduce the latency of something like this (which is often quite a waste for time regarding the performance-gain/development-time balance). Maybe you should focus on improving the throughput of your computation by using SIMD instructions (possibly done by the compilers based on a SIMD-friendly C++ code). Modern mainstream CPUs can operate on typically 4 double-precision numbers per instruction and 2 instructions per cycle, so 8 double/cycle. Not to mention throughput-bound code are often well pipelined.

Comment: @JérômeRichard: If you do this in a loop that can vectorize, an array is garbage.  You'd hope for it to vectorize to something like `vpcmpeqd` against zero and `vpmovsxdq` to widen 32 bit compare results to 64-bit, for a `vpblendvpd`.  Or if the compiler is really clever or you're manually vectorizing, shift the uint and OR it into `1.0` as the sign bit.  Like `vpmovzxdq ymm0, [rdi]` (u32 to u64 load) / `vpsllq ymm0, 63` / `vpor ymm0, ymm1`.

Comment: It would of course be even more efficient with 32 bit `float` since no widening would be needed.  But OTOH, wasting 4 bytes per single bit in your 0/1 data isn't good for cache footprint / memory bandwidth, so 1 byte per bit is good; CPUs can easily widen that when loading.  Packing 8 bits per byte is also doable especially if you can vectorize (*[is there an inverse instruction to the movemask instruction in intel avx2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36488675)*), or unroll a scalar loop by 8 so you don't need a nested loop that's right-shifting.

Comment: *I cannot rely on x86-specific bit formats* - x86 uses IEEE 754 binary32 and binary64 floating point for `float` and `double`; those are very portable formats.  These days you'd have to look hard to find any system that didn't use those.  So you can just OR `1<<63` or `0<<63` with the MSB of the `+1.0` `double` to get `-1.0` or `+1.0`.

Comment: @Peter Cordes I'm not wasting bits. I get the {0,1} bit from an (uint64_t & 1)

Comment: That's not what you're benchmarking!  Your question also mixes up `int` (a 32-bit type in GNU C for x86-64) with English "integer", and your benchmark functions actually use `unsigned int` (a 32-bit type), although I just noticed you have an array of `unsigned long long`. Your benchmark does more assigning to `volatile` than needed, both inside the functions and with the retval. Anyway, if you have packed bitmaps, good.  You'll want to load them in chunks of 8 bits if using AVX2.  Or with scalar, I guess an inner loop of 64 iterations to do `signbit = bitmap << 63;  bitmap >>= 1;` could work.

Comment: @Peter Cordes Thanks for warning about my messing up with theints. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect something like

```
double func(uint64_t x) {
    union {
        double f;
        uint64_t x;
    } v;
    v.f = 1.0;
    v.x |= x << 63;
    return v.f;
}
```

to be about the fastest on any machine where `double` is an IEEE 64-bit floating point.

[compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Kj78xY7P4) shows it just needing a constant + shift + or

Comment: I just realized that for the OP's microbenchmark of just storing to memory (not doing any `double` math with it), it can use purely integer operations.  Unlike here where a non-inline function has to return the `double` in XMM0 so it uses `movq xmm0, rax`.  Yay for winning at benchmarks which probably don't represent the OP's real use-case...

Comment: You shouldn't assume that union type-punning is well-defined in portable C++; ISO C++ doesn't define it.  Use memcpy, or better, C++20 `std::bit_cast<double>( or_result )`.  It's `constexpr` so you could use `uint64_t onebits = std::bit_cast<uint64_t>( 1.0 );` to avoid hard-coding the bit-pattern.  https://godbolt.org/z/zrb35dfe3 shows it compiles the same with GCC / clang, which do define the behaviour of union type-punning as C99.

Comment: Note that this benefits more from inlining than most; the 10-byte instruction `movabs  rax, 4607182418800017408` is not great if it has to run every time, but the constant can be reused across iterations.  Maybe especially if we write it as `+` instead of `|` so it can use LEA to copy-and-add if it wants, although it doesn't need the `x<<63` value later so it can OR into the register holding it.

Comment: Unlike the OP's lookup table, this can vectorize nicely.  The OP's casting versions suffer from uint64_t to `double` not being directly supported in hardware, and from the function not inlining to see the value-range is limited to 0 or 1 so it could just do signed int32 or int64 conversion.  But those still can't vectorize as easily (for unpacked uint64_t arrays like the OP is benchmarking) since x86 vector conversion instructions only provide signed 32-bit <-> double or float until AVX-512.  The OP says they actually have packed u64 data, 64 bools per u64, so vectors need shuffling.

Comment: I added your solution to the benchmark, with an `#ifdef` to stop the compilation on non IEEE compliant platforms. It is a bit slower than Peter Cordes  proposal (benchmarked as IEEE_754_binary64_floating), and I do not understand why. I cannot run it in compiler explorer (requires c++20 and `#include <bit>`. Maybe it runs faster in newer computers, but I do not have one to test.

Answer (score 0):

(EDIT: ran the benchmark in 2 loops to warm up the processor and benchmark all functions in equality of conditions)

(EDIT: Peter Cordes suggestion to overwrite the sign in `double(1.0)` is even faster)

(EDIT: Added Chris Dodd Union to the benchmark)

Based on the comment from Howard Hinnant, I found this one to be the fastest, but I'm not sure if it is meaningful in real code.
Declaring constArrayMap as constexpr seems to help, but I do not get consistent benchmarks runs on my PC.

```
constexpr double constArrayMap[2] = {1.0, -1.0};
constexpr double constexprArray(uint64_t uintFlag)
{

  volatile double answer = constArrayMap[uintFlag]; //volatile is only used for benchmarking
  return answer;
}
```

I do not get consistent benchmarks between runnings, but this is a typical benchmark

```
Average time for IEEE_754_binary64_floating: 305.600000 nanoseconds
Average time for chrisDoddUnion: 349.400000 nanoseconds
Average time for constexprArray: 305.800000 nanoseconds
Average time for getFromArray: 345.300000 nanoseconds
Average time for getFromConstArray: 337.500000 nanoseconds
Average time for ifBranching: 736.700000 nanoseconds
Average time for mathFormulaCastingAsBOOL: 833.300000 nanoseconds
Average time for mathFormulaCastingtoFloat: 452.200000 nanoseconds
Average time for mathFormulaDelayedCastingtoFloat: 818.900000 nanoseconds
Average time for switchBranching: 796.300000 nanoseconds
```

I was hoping to get smething like a `GOTO uintFlag*space`, or some bitwise trick to choose between 2 constants. Something like this (which DOESN'T WORKS)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>
#include <random>
#include <bit>

using namespace std;

typedef double (*conversion_function)(uint64_t);

inline double ifBranching(uint64_t uintFlag)
{
  double answer = uintFlag ? double(-1.0) : double(1.0);
  return answer;
}

#ifndef __GCC_IEC_559
#error chrisDoddUnion() function requires IEEE 754 Standard
#endif

constexpr union
{
  double f;
  uint64_t uint;
} v = {.f = 1.0};

constexpr double chrisDoddUnion(uint64_t uintFlag)
{
  union
  {
    double f;
    uint64_t uint;
  } answer = {.uint = v.uint | uintFlag << 63};
  return answer.f;
}

double switchBranching(uint64_t uintFlag)
{
  // double answer;
  switch (uintFlag)
  {
  case 0:
    return double(1.0);
  case 1:
    return double(-1.0);
  }
  return 0;
}

double arrayMap[2] = {1.0, -1.0};

double getFromArray(uint64_t uintFlag)
{
  double answer = arrayMap[uintFlag];
  return answer;
}

constexpr double constArrayMap[2] = {1.0, -1.0};
double getFromConstArray(uint64_t uintFlag)
{
  double answer = constArrayMap[uintFlag];
  return answer;
}

double mathFormulaCastingToFloat(uint64_t uintFlag)
{
  double answer = double(1.0 - 2.0 * uintFlag);
  return answer;
}

double mathFormulaDelayedCastingToFloat(uint64_t uintFlag)
{
  double answer = 1 - 2 * uint64_t(uintFlag);
  return answer;
}

double mathFormulaCastingAsBOOL(uint64_t uintFlag)
{
  double answer = 1 - 2 * bool(uintFlag);
  return answer;
}

#ifndef __GCC_IEC_559
#error IEEE_754_binary64_floating() function requires IEEE 754 Standard
#endif

constexpr uint64_t ONE = bit_cast<uint64_t>(double(1.0));

constexpr double IEEE_754_binary64_floating(uint64_t uintFlag)
{
  double answer = bit_cast<double>(ONE | (uintFlag << 63u));
  return answer;
}

constexpr double constexprArray(uint64_t uintFlag)
{
  double answer = constArrayMap[uintFlag];
  return answer;
}

int main()
{
  const int numRuns = 100000;
  unsigned long long uintFlag[numRuns];
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 gen(rd());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 1);

  for (int i = 0; i < numRuns; i++)
  {
    uintFlag[i] = dis(gen);
  }

  map<string, conversion_function> conversion_functions;
  conversion_functions["ifBranching"] = ifBranching;
  conversion_functions["getFromArray"] = getFromArray;
  conversion_functions["getFromConstArray"] = getFromConstArray;
  conversion_functions["constexprArray"] = constexprArray;
  conversion_functions["chrisDoddUnion"] = chrisDoddUnion;
  conversion_functions["IEEE_754_binary64_floating"] = IEEE_754_binary64_floating;
  conversion_functions["switchBranching"] = switchBranching;
  conversion_functions["mathFormulaCastingAsBOOL"] = mathFormulaCastingAsBOOL;
  conversion_functions["mathFormulaCastingtoFloat"] = mathFormulaCastingToFloat;
  conversion_functions["mathFormulaDelayedCastingtoFloat"] = mathFormulaDelayedCastingToFloat;

  // Warm up the processor
  for (auto &[functionName, function] : conversion_functions)
  {
    for (auto flag : uintFlag)
    {
      volatile double tmp = function(flag);
    }
  }

  // benchmarking

  for (auto &[functionName, function] : conversion_functions)
  {
    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    _mm_prefetch(constArrayMap, _MM_HINT_T0);
    for (auto flag : uintFlag)

    {
      volatile double tmp = function(flag);
    }

    auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto totalDuration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count();

    auto x = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(chrono::seconds(totalDuration));
    string strDuration = to_string(x.count() / 1e12);
    cout << "Average time for " << functionName << ": " << strDuration << " nanoseconds" << endl;
  }
  cout << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Optimizers will tear this logic down and rebuild it to suit their understanding of the pipeline state produced by the surrounding code. How you express calculations like this matters very little these days and the results depend on ... everything. Compiler version, hardware, options, surrounding code, … everything. And you're talking about nanoseconds here, if even that.

Comment: @jthill This is a single line in a critical piece of code, and optimizing each line is justified.

Comment: Then benchmarking it separately like this, in the absence of that entire critical piece of code is likely to mislead—and if benchmarking it *with* the rest of the code swamps your metrics, then your choice makes no measurable difference in context.

Comment: @jthill I cannot post the entire code to ask this. I had to write a 9 page PDF to explain it.

Comment: I bet on the conditional operator. Ideally on a modern machine it can run branchless. The ideal compiler output would look like (pseudo register transfer logic): `flag_reg.zbit=uintflag_reg.bit0; result_reg=1.0; result_reg.sign_bit =flag_reg.zbit`. But this is my speculation.   Disassembly of the code can talk.

Comment: Try the different ways in the context of the entire critical piece of code with your current toolchain and hardware and compile options, and go with whichever setup i measurably faster *in that context*. That's the only answer.

Comment: Agreed with jthill; this is such a small operation that the surrounding code matters ([Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987) / [How many CPU cycles are needed for each assembly instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44980899) (that's not a very meaningful question for modern CPUs)).  You very likely don't want to branch, but it matters a *lot* if your real use-case can auto-vectorize; this benchmark can't since you're only assigning the results to `volatile`.  And you left out the part where you have 64 bits packed into each `uint64_t`

Comment: Your `std::map` of conversion functions defeats inlining with `g++ -O3 -march=skylake` on my desktop!!  Function-call overhead is significant for something this tiny.  (And your repeat counts are very low; the whole program only runs for 3 milliseconds, so repeated runs are needed to get the CPU up to max turbo.)  Even with inlining, the compiler also won't know that the incoming values are always 0 or 1 like it would if they were the result of `var & 1`.

Comment: @Peter Cordes I don't know how to tell to the compiler that the uint64_t only holds '1' significant bit. Maybe casting as boolean?

Comment: Maybe generating random uint64_t bit-patterns and having an inner loop over their bits... like you would in your real program.  Of course doing it in the caller only helps if these functions inline.  Doing `uintFlag &= 1` inside each of your test functions would add the overhead of one scalar `and` instruction to each one, but then the compiler would have that value-range info.

Comment: You didn't show how you compiled (`-O3 -march=native`?),  GCC version, or what CPU you tested on.  `mathFormulaCastingtoFloat` benefits from FMA for example, using `vcvtsi2sd` for int to double conversion and `vfnmadd132sd` for `1.0 - 2*cvtresult`.  BTW, I tried adding `&=1` to each function but GCC doesn't do anything differently.  So much overhead from call/ret and from `volatile double answer` hide the differences in the faster functions.

Comment: @Peter Cordes `-O3` C++23, Mingw-w64, running in i3-2350M.  
Volatile is necessary to stop the compiler from ignoring unused `answer`, and skipping the code. Your suggestion to overwrite the sign bit of the `double(1.0)` is the fastest, but I added an ifdef to detect IEEE 754, and found that mingW uses a different `#ifdef` constant than other compilers. I guess that it sets the limit on how fast it can be.

Comment: `volatile double answer = function(flag);` is the caller is necessary.  `volatile tmp = whatever;` / `return tmp;` inside each function is *not*; that compiles to an extra store/reload for each call, on top of push/pop of the return address and storing the result in the caller.

Comment: Until AVX-512, x86 doesn't have single-instruction u64 <-> double conversion, and without value-range information your cast versions probably got slower because it has to use multiple instructions now.  On a CPU with AVX-512 (like Zen 4 or Ice Lake), you'd probably find those were as fast as before you made the args wider.  You could fix it with `uintFlag &= 1` inside those functions.

Comment: Your benchmark results of `262.1` for `IEEE_754_binary64_floating` vs. `347.8` for `chrisDoddUnion` cast serious doubt on the precision of your testing.  Those functions compile to identical asm (with recent GCC and Clang with normal levels of optimization enabled.)   https://godbolt.org/z/TGn91j4x9 . Unless there's some weird code-alignment effect, they should run at the same speed.  The fact they don't is a sign of huge noise in your measurements, maybe from making only one pass over a big array instead of multiple passes over a smaller array. (Many more, to get longer timed intervals.)

Comment: @Peter Cordes I do not understand what is wrong with the benchmark. I wish somebody else ran it in a newer pc.

Comment: @tutozeri you could alias the existing type for uintFlag to a struct which allows you to access a pair of int32 objects although you then need to beware of big vs little endian CPUs. The speed gain from an int32 might be worth the pain. One other option not mentioned so far as I can see is load 1.0 and then do a conditional negation of the FP value. TBH I don't think your timings are anything like accurate or representative of how the code will behave in a real life situation. Concrete example is MSC cbrt which benchmarks very badly indeed but timing is OK  in real usage (accuracy isn't).

Comment: I've mentioned repeatedly that one huge problem is not letting these tiny functions inline.  Another problem is the very short timed intervals with no warm-up (other than random-number generation) to let the CPU get up from idle to max turbo unless you had something running before the program started.  It's Sandybridge so it doesn't have hardware P-state management.  As mentioned in [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60291987) which I linked earlier, a good benchmark library like https://github.com/google/benchmark is a good way to test stuff like this.

Comment: @Peter Cordes I added a warm up loop, and it makes the results more consistent, yet it doesn't explain the differences between code that compile to the same assembler.  
As I understand, the functions call should cause the same constant overhead for all options, except to soften the percentage of difference .

Comment: *As I understand, the functions call should cause the same constant overhead for all options* - No, functions that need to prepare a register (e.g. with a large constant value like `uint64_t ONE`) can do that once outside the loop if the function inlines, instead of every iteration.  So not inlining hurts them more.

Comment: Also, the execution ports needed for `call r64` (p5 + p2 or 3 + p4) and `ret` (p5 + p2 or p3) instructions on Sandybridge (https://uops.info/ and https://agner.org/optimize) might compete more or less with some code than others, and quirks of code-fetch from the uop cache can be magnified with jumps.  Or not if the loop buffer can lock down the uops (see also [Is performance reduced when executing loops whose uop count is not a multiple of processor width?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39311872) which is specifically relevant to first-gen Sandybridge, the CPU I had when getting those results).

Comment: Actually GCC used `call   QWORD PTR [rbp+0x40]` (not hoisting the function-pointer into a register, only the map entry) so it's a memory indirect call: p5 + 2x p2/3 + p4.  Instructions like `movq xmm0, r64` also compete for port 5.  Anyway, modern CPUs (including yours from a decade ago) are superscalar with out-of-order exec so costs don't add up linearly in cycles: [How many CPU cycles are needed for each assembly instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44980899) - BeeOnRope's answer explains how it works.

Comment: The amount of code you're benchmarking is so small that it really does matter even in asm what the surrounding code is.  It matters even more in C++ because the compiler might optimize these operations into the surrounding shifts or bit-masking that get bits out of a `uint64_t` if you have it packed instead of 1 per u64, generating different asm for some of these strategies.  Especially if you use the results in a way that it can auto-vectorize, but maybe even for scalar.  This small an amount of code is too small to benchmark very meaningfuly on its own.